# How to transfer call log data?

Tags: android

- My end goal is to design an app that upon installation automatically retrieves all call history data and pushes it to the database, preferably in csv format. There will be a data science model performed on the data, and the results will be sent back to the app for display.
- I wanted to ask if this is even possible for an app to do? If so, what is the like basic algorithm I should go for?
  P.s.:I am a data science student, and I am looking at android code for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can read the call logs, heres something to start with

First enable the permission in your manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />`

You also need to request the permission from the permission manager

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED {
  // Get data from database
}
else {
  // Request permission from user
}
```

**Get data from database**

```
val projection = arrayOf(
            CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE)

val cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null)
        if(cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Data for your database
                val name: String = cursor.getString(0)
                val number: String = cursor.getString(1)
                val type: String = cursor.getString(2)
                val time: String = cursor.getString(3)
            }
            cursor.close()
        }
```